# difference among "Density-compatibility" and "Size-compatibility" android

Tags: android

Can someone explaing the difference among "Density-compatibility" and "Size-compatibility" please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find this overview of [Screen information](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading that ... but I didn't understand it vague...so I had posted this question..

Comment: @poddroid - I'll make examples extreme so as to illustrate the point.  Size is the physical size of the display.  Imagine a screen that is 100ft long - that would be massive.  But that says nothing of the density of the display.  Maybe on that 100ft screen there are only 5px per row and 5 rows.  Or maybe that 100ft screen has 10000px per row.  Can you envision the quality difference of those two hypothetical devices?  The how many pixels gives you an incite to the actual density of the display.  One with more pixels has a higher density.

Comment: @poddroid - So a device can be high or low density, which is essentially 'how much can I fit in one area of space?', while saying nothing about the physical size of the display.  Android allows you to filter out phones based on either of those criteria.

Comment: Many thanks. I understanding now is perfect. Thanks once again